# Проблема с проверкой пароля js

Tags: javascript, html

аналогичный код проверяет текстовую строку с другой регуляркой на ура, не скажу что код супер но работает, при проверке пароля и замене регулярки ничего не работает, вопрос дело в регулярке, или в том что парорль не считывается так как тип password? или еще в чем?

---

```
  <div class="rov">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <label for="pass_1">Пароль</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <input type="password" onkeyup="ValidPassw()" id="pass_1"  class="form-control"  placeholder="Пароль" >
        </div>      
        <div class="col-md-1">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="display:none;color:green;" aria-hidden="true" id="okPass"></span>
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="display:none;color:red;" aria-hidden="true" id="noPass"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

---

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ValidPassw() {
            var P = ((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}) ;
            var Pass = document.getElementById('pass_1').value;
            var valid = P.test(pass);
            if (valid) {
                document.getElementById('okPass').style.display = 'block';
                document.getElementById('noPass').style.display = 'none';
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('okPass').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('noPass').style.display = 'block';
            }
            return valid;
        };
    </script >
```

Comment: лучше выбирать имя переменных и функций так чтобы первое слово было в нижнем регистре(например, camelCase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так должно работать. Что бы был зелёный крестик, измени регулярное выражение.
P.S. Для обработки при каждом клике, лучше использовать `oninput`

```js
function ValidPassw() {
  var pass = document.getElementById('pass_1').value;
  if (/((?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15})/.exec(pass)) {
    document.getElementById('okPass').style.display = 'block';
    document.getElementById('noPass').style.display = 'none';
  }else{
    document.getElementById('okPass').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('noPass').style.display = 'block';
  };
  return false;
};
```

```html
<div class="rov">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <label for="pass_1">Пароль:</label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-7">
    <input type="password" oninput="ValidPassw()" id="pass_1"  class="form-control" placeholder="Пароль">
  </div>      
  <div class="col-md-1">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" style="display:none;color:green;" aria-hidden="true" id="okPass">X</span>
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="display:none;color:red;" aria-hidden="true" id="noPass">X</span>
  </div>
</div>
```